# React components not rendering on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku

Created a react rails app using react-rails gem but when uploaded on heroku the react components are all missing. It works fine on my local server though. Here's the package.json file in case i missed out anything. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    {
  "name": "my_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console ?

Comment: @morissetcl nope everything seems alright on the console but the bootstrap/react/redux components aren't appearing

Answer (score 0):

Yes you missed to set the homepage where to redirect the component, So Need to Set the Homepage after the taking the build of your project

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "private": true,
  "homepage":"/build" or "/path of your project build" ,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Home page is necessory while deploying the react project.

Comment: I added the homepage but still the same problem, majority of the react and bootstrap stuff are missing

Comment: is those are missing in the bundled file?

Comment: I think it might be because of the buildpack

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reload the page by ,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).